# Value of $\int\tan^{-1}(x)\,dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

What is the value of $\int^{1000}_{0}\tan^{-1}(x)\,\mathrm d x$?

Today we were taught about graphs of all trigonometric inverse functions.  So my proofessor split it into $0-\tan(1)$ and $\tan(1)-1000$ and got the answer as $1000-\tan(1)$, but it was taught to us not in integration but in graphs and functions.

So my question is whether we have any way if we don't know the exact graphs.

Comment: Are you sure that is the answer you got? For $x>10$, we have $\tan^{-1}x\approx\frac{\pi}{2}$, so $\int_0^{1000}\approx500\pi\approx1500$.

Comment: In the original post, did you mean the *integer part* of $\tan^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: Yes its greatest integer function

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\int \arctan x \  dx = \int x^0 \arctan x \ dx $$

Now use by parts formula

$$\int f(x) g(x) \,dx = f(x)\int g(x)\,dx - \int \left(f'(x) \int g(x)\,dx \right) dx$$

using $f(x) = \arctan x$ (and $g(x) = x^0$)

Answer (score 2):

As almagest commented, there is something strange.

Consider $$I=\int\tan^{-1}(x)\, dx$$ Integrate by parts $$u=\tan^{-1}(x)\implies u'=\frac 1{1+x^2}\qquad , \qquad v'=dx\implies v=x$$ So $$I=x\tan^{-1}(x)-\int\frac x {1+x^2} dx=x \tan ^{-1}(x)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(x^2+1\right)$$ So, using the bounds $$\int^{1000}_{0}\tan^{-1}(x)\ d x=1000 \tan ^{-1}(1000)-\frac{\log (1000001)}{2}\approx 1562.89$$

For an estimation of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ when $x$ is large, you could use the relation $$\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(\frac 1x)=\frac \pi 2$$ which gives, for large $x$ $$\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int \arctan x \, dx & = \overbrace{\int u \, dx = ux - \int x\,du}^\text{integration by parts} \\[10pt]
& = x\arctan x - \int x\, \frac{dx}{1+x^2} \\[10pt]
& = x\arctan x - \frac 1 2 \int \frac 1 {1+x^2} \Big(2x\,dx\Big) \\[10pt]
& = x\arctan x - \frac 1 2 \int \frac 1 w \, dw \\[10pt]
& = x\arctan x - \frac 1 2 \log |w| + C \\[10pt]
& = x\arctan x - \frac 1 2 \log(1+x^2) + C.
\end{align}
Now you can plug in $0$ (and get $0$) and $1000$, and realize that $\arctan1000\approx\dfrac \pi 2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\left(x \tan^{-1}x \right)'=\tan^{-1} x+\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$